# PHP check the exist of data in array and prevent from adding data

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add array to an array of array. Then do checking on the existence of previous added array . Here is how I do the checking.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++){
  $data = array(
        'order_id' => $invoice->order_id,            
      );

  $datas = array(); 
  // this is the array contains array I create to 
  // let me check whether $data exist in it.

  foreach ($datas as $value){

  if ($value['order_id']==$data['order_id']){ 
      //if the $data already exist in $datas  
      print "ok";
  }    

  $datas = array_push($datas,$data); 
  // push $data to $datas for the next checking of existing of $data, 
  // that means, next time if same order id exist, it will be found in 
  // the above checking. 
}
```

However, the code seems not working, what's the proper way to do this?

The error message:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Comment: What part isn't working? If inside the foreach you use continue then it will skip to the next iteration of the foreach loop. Or is the if statement not catching the correct thing?

Comment: Can you change your pseudo code with real input and correct code syntax. It's completely unclear how's your input array look, what you want to compare and what desired output you want?

Comment: `$datas = array(); 
  foreach ($datas as $value3){` this will never-ever work

Comment: Share original code ?

Comment: $datas = array(); foreach ($datas as $value3) never work. so the correct way is? May be I loop it using for. So my question is how to put array to an array of aray.

Comment: $datas is empty

Comment: And you have missing `}` for the `foreach`

Comment: What you want to do if data is already exist ?

Comment: I will add the data to Drupal queue for later processing.

Comment: I have another question related to array_push. I will create another question .

Comment: You will always get same value in `$invoice->order_id,` and after first iteration all next will be same.

Comment: Your problem is this line $datas = array();

Answer (score 0):

You code have several errors.

1. `$datas` is empty (comment of mwweb)
2. `foreach` have a missing `}`

I would advice you to use a associative array to check if your order is already part of the data:

```
$datas[$data['order_id']] = $data;
```

then you can check it with `isset($datas[$data['order_id']])`